# Terraform loop through JSON array to create iam users

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I have a simple json file containing a list of users and groups.  From this list, I would like to create the users in AWS IAM but my `for_each` or `merging` syntax is wrong.
When running `terraform plan`, I get the following error:

```
Error: Error in function call
│ 
│   on locals.tf line 3, in locals:
│    3:   json_data  = merge([for f in local.json_files : jsondecode(file("${path.module}/input/${f}"))]...)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.json_files is set of string with 1 element
│     │ path.module is "."
│ 
│ Call to function "merge" failed: arguments must be maps or objects, got "tuple".
```

How do I properly loop through the list (tuple) of objects in the JSON file?

**JSON File sample:**

```json
[
  { "name": "user1", "groups": ["Admins", "DevOps"], "policies": [] },
  { "name": "user2", "groups": ["DevOps"], "policies": [] }
]
```

**Terraform Code:**

```
locals {
  json_files = fileset("${path.module}/input/", "*.json")
  json_data  = merge([for f in local.json_files : jsondecode(file("${path.module}/input/${f}"))]...)
}

resource "aws_iam_user" "create_new_users" {
  for_each = local.json_data
  name     = each.name
}
```

**As a side note, I did manage to get the service to work by changing the JSON file to the following structure, but prefer to use the former:**

```json
{
  "user1": {"groups": ["Admins","DevOps"],"policies": []},
  "user2": {"groups": ["DevOps"],"policies": []}
}
```

and updating the `aws_iam_user` resource to:

```
resource "aws_iam_user" "create_new_users" {
  for_each = local.json_data
  name     = each.key
}
```

Comment: Is there more than one JSON file? What is it you want to achieve with merging content of two different files?

Comment: There is more than one JSON file yes.  For various reasons, we use separate files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON document you showed is using a JSON array, which corresponds with the tuple type in Terraform, so it doesn't make sense to use `merge` for that result -- `merge` is for merging together *maps*, which would correspond most closely with an object in JSON. (and indeed, that's why your second example with an object containing a property with each user worked).

For sequence-like types (lists and tuples) there is a similar function `concat` which will append them together to produce a single longer sequence containing all of the items in the order given. You could use that function instead of `merge` to get a single list of all of the users as a starting point:

```
locals {
  json_files = fileset("${path.module}/input/", "*.json")
  json_data  = concat([for f in local.json_files : jsondecode(file("${path.module}/input/${f}"))]...)
}
```

The resource `for_each` argument wants a mapping type though, so you'll need to do one more step to project this list of objects into a map of objects using the `name` attribute values as the keys:

```
resource "aws_iam_user" "create_new_users" {
  for_each = { for u in local.json_data : u.name => u }

  name = each.value.name
}
```

This will cause Terraform to identify each instance of the resource by the object's "name" property, and so with the sample input file you showed this will declare two instances of this resource with the following addresses:

- `aws_iam_user.create_new_users["user1"]`
- `aws_iam_user.create_new_users["user2"]`

---

(Note that it's unusual to name a Terraform resource using a verb. Terraform doesn't understand English grammar of course, so it doesn't really matter what you name it, but it's more typical to use a noun because this is only describing that a set of users *should exist*; you'll use this same object later to describe updating or destroying these objects. If this JSON document just represents *all* of your users then a more typical name might be `aws_iam_user.all`, since the resource type already says that these are users -- so there's no need to restate that -- and so all that's left to say is *which* users these are.)

Comment: Hi Martin, Thank you so much!   That works perfectly.  I appreciate you taking the time to also briefly explain the general functionality and approach.  
In terms of the naming convention; it's duly noted.    I will definitely update the resource names to nouns rather than verbs.